# Saving Photo to a Specific Directory

Tags: ios, uiimage, directory, save

I want to save photo in directory.  However I made directories called hats bottoms right and left using this code in the view controller.

```
  NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hats",@"bottoms",@"right",@"left",nil];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

    for (int i = 0; i < [directoryNames count] ; i++) {
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:i]];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder
```

The UIImage is displaying what the user has shot in the camera in the app.  I would want to save the photo automatically to one of my directories that I made(for example hats) when it is displayed on the UIIMage.Below is my code for displaying to UIImage after photo is taken.  Is there away to automatically save to one of the directories?? I can't do the place where you save to a specific directory.

```
- (void) processImage:(UIImage *)image { //process captured image, crop, resize and rotate
    haveImage = YES;

    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { //Device is ipad
        // Resize image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(768, 1022));
        [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1022)];
        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 130, 768, 768);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);
        //or use the UIImage wherever you like

        [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    }else{ //Device is iphone
        // Resize image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 426));
        [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 426)];
        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 55, 320, 320);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);

        [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    }

    //adjust image orientation based on device orientation
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"landscape left image");

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-90));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"landscape right");

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(90));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSLog(@"upside down");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(180));
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"upside upright");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        captureImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(0));
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}







- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)switchCamera:(id)sender { //switch cameras front and rear cameras
    if (cameraSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        FrontCamera = YES;
        [self initializeCamera];
    }
    else {
        FrontCamera = NO;
        [self initializeCamera];
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

```
    NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMAGE_NAME_HERE.PNG"]; // you maybe want to incorporate a timestamp into the name to avoid duplicates
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(captureImage.image);
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Automatically saving is just saving without explicitly asking the user if you should. The process of saving the image is identical:

1. Get your instance of `UIImage`
2. Convert to data (using `UIImageJpegRepresentation` or `UIImagePngRepresentation`)
3. Save the data (using `writeToFile:atomically:`)

---

Something like:

```
folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryNames[0]];
```

or

```
folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hats"];
```

Comment: Ok I I have done what you have told me however I still don't get how to specify the directory that I made. I just want to save the image to directory right.

Comment: In the code at the top of your question you get the directory paths in order to ensure they exist...

Comment: `        NSString *folderPath = [NSDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryNames[%]];` Do you mean this? I where do you put the directory name?

Comment: `directoryNames[%]` - did you write all of the code in your question? Do you understand what it all does?

Comment: Yes I do however I do not know the first line of this the line that has directory names and especially the what goes in the percent sign.

Comment: wait、I did that however I get an error saying if I want to replace with `NSDocumentDirectory`, and if i replace it I get an error saying undeclared identifier directoryNames

Comment: Anything you want to use needs to be declared in a scope that is visible from your current code. Simple option - copy the code from your earlier method. Better option, add helper methods and instance variables.